# Is there a new version for the flutter tflite package?

Tags: flutter, gradle, tensorflow-lite, google-mlkit, flutter-packages

I started working with Flutter and Dart lately, and I'm building a project using the tflite package. But when I want to build the app, even the demo app when just adding the tflite package to my dependencies in pubspec.yaml, to my phone (Xiaomi redmi note 10, android 12) it shows this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Pub\Cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\tflite-1.1.2\android\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':tflite'.
> No signature of method: build_9lbq7rfhl5cpix99148s3txh6.android() is applicable for argument types: (build_9lbq7rfhl5cpix99148s3txh6$_run_closure2) values: [build_9lbq7rfhl5cpix99148s3txh6$_run_closure2@77b9e791]

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

Also, when I firstly clicked 'pub get' after depending on tflite, it showed this error:

```
The plugin `tflite` uses a deprecated version of the Android embedding.
To avoid unexpected runtime failures, or future build failures, try to see if this plugin supports the Android V2 embedding. Otherwise, consider removing it since a future release of Flutter will remove these deprecated APIs.
If you are plugin author, take a look at the docs for migrating the plugin to the V2 embedding: https://flutter.dev/go/android-plugin-migration.
```

but since I am not the package author, i didn't thought much of it.

I've seen that the tflite package was lastly updated 18 months ago.

So, is there an updated version of the package? Or, is there an alternative for running the google teachable machine?

Comment: Im having this exact issue, did you work out how to solve it?

Answer (score 1):

That is the last known edit to the package. If there are issues that make it unusable now, I'd suggest leaving an issue on their GitHub page so that they can address it moving forward. Unfortunately, you might have to find an alternative to using that package, or edit the package locally yourself to get rid of any dependency issues.

Judging from the volume of issues on this package raised on github (https://github.com/shaqian/flutter_tflite), I don't think it's being maintained at all anymore.

Comment: Thank you. I'll see what I need to edit.